# Macbook Pro 2019 Bootable USB install stuck on Network spinning globe

Tags: macos, startup

I believe I have lost access to recovery mode (cmd + R) as the main disk has been completely wiped out.

I created an "install MacOS Monterey" disk. I can see it ok, but on selection, it leads me to the "Choose Network..." with a spinning globe.

This eventually fails after a few minutes with [this error](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253760512#:%7E:text=The%20flashing%20folder%20means%20the,need%20to%20install%20in%20OS.)

Is there anything I can do to proceed with the installation?

Comment: use Ethernet cable not wifi

Comment: Is that going to fix it for sure? I'll need to buy one.

Comment: Think of it this way. The OS is not working, thus the WiFi is not working, but the hard wire internet is still there. The WiFi needs bit more from OS then the hard wire.

Comment: I managed to get my hands on a ethernet adapter. I've tested it with another computer (connected tight now). But, on the device with issues, it's still prompting for a wifi connection.

Comment: Update: I came across a solution on the internet where someone suggested this could be due to internet in Australia (where I live). I tried my phone hotspot and it has progressed further. Apparently ethernet is prioritised lower than wifi by default so the ethernet solution didn't work for me.

Comment: *"I created an "install MacOS Monterey" disk"* How did you create this? If it correctly sees a bootable USB, it has no need to go to Internet Recovery.. which tells me the USB isn't working. See https://osxdaily.com/2022/02/23/make-macos-monterey-boot-install-drive/

Comment: I was able to create it using another mac.